# How can I produce a std::shared_ptr that has locality with it's control block but is an aggregate of another class?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

`std::make_shared` produces, on the heap, an control block/object pair requiring only one allocation and keeping the control block and object in close proximity to help locality.

I'd want to do this, except I want it to be created as an aggregate component of another class.  I've looked around, but I don't see such a beast around.  Am I missing something?

E.g.

```
struct Bar {};
struct Foo
{
  // This would allocate the control block and object Bar on
  // the heap, which is pointed at by Foo.
  std::shared_ptr<Bar> x;

  // Example that would allocate the control block and object Bar as
  // an aggregate part of Foo. local_shared_ptr is not an actual thing
  // in the stl that I can find.
  std::local_shared_ptr<Bar> y;
}
```

Comment: You can't have shared ownership without also having the object's memory location's lifetime be independently managed. Shared ownership means that the object will be destroyed when the last of it's owner releases it, whichever owner that happens to be. Here, `y`'s lifetime could never exceed the lifetime of `Foo` so the `Foo` has unique ownership of it. Edit : I understood that you want to have the `Bar` exist within `Foo`'s storage instead of residing in the free store. Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Jarod42, presumably just like you would do when you assign to a `std::shared_ptr` to a pair using `std::make_shared`, you redirect the control block pointer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, sure you can.  If the object is deleted, then we do something like we do with `std::optional`, just don't call the destructor if the object isn't being pointed at by the control block.

Comment: My concern is if the `Foo` which holds the storage for the `Bar` is destroyed, that storage has to be released immediately so you have no choice but to also destroy the `Bar`. In that sense, the ownership is not shared. The `Foo` would need the authority to destroy the `Bar` even if other owners still need it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, hmmmm, good point.  I want the lifetime to be managed by the encompassing class, but I want weak pointer semantics.  Possible?

Comment: A weak_ptr implementation needs to store a state in a way that is independent of the owned object because when that object is destroyed you need to be able to express that state (of not longer existing). It's also not practical to store that information in the weak_ptr handles themselves, since you can have many and none can be considered special. Well, maybe you could make that work, but it sounds tricky. So you're back to having at least a control block dynamically allocated.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, that is not true. You can have weak pointers form a list and zero them all once the object is being destroyed.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, hmmmm, I guess it would depend on implementation.  You could have weak pointers which are just a linked list, and the shared control block would be linked into that list, allowing nulling each shared pointer and removing the weak pointer from the list.

Comment: @zch, it would depend on the implementation.  If the control block has a lifetime that must exceed the weak pointers because the weak pointers point at the control block, then that wouldn't work.  It would work if using the implementation that I describe in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56654792/how-can-i-produce-a-stdshared-ptr-that-has-locality-with-its-control-block-bu?noredirect=1#comment99880043_56654792) comment.

Comment: @zch Sounds like it could work. Synchronizing it might be tricky though.

Comment: From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr): `Like std::shared_ptr, a typical implementation of weak_ptr stores two pointers:

a pointer to the control block; and
the stored pointer of the shared_ptr it was constructed from.`  That is a typical implementation, which wouldn't work with what I need.

Comment: @Adrian Sure, but when you consider a shared control block you come back to having a dynamically allocated control block which is contrary to the initial goal. And to be clear, with the proposed design, you have to forget about shared ownership period. At best, what's been called weak pointers in this context are just checked pointers, pointers that point to an object and know whether or not it's still there. They aren't weak pointer. They can't be locked to gain ownership because this type of ownership cannot be shared. The `Foo` owns the `Bar`, it's unique ownership.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, right, so this is a dead end.  Thanks.

Comment: @Adrian I'd consider zch's proposal which does not use a control block and seems like it could achieve your goals. My only concern with it is that it may be hard to make it thread-safe without a control block. Edit : Actually, if you just have the object keep list of all the weak_ptrs to itself, the weak_ptrs don't need anything more than a pointer to the object. You can null them when the object is destroyed. Maybe this is what zch meant to whole time and I just misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the lifetime to be managed by the encompassing class, but I want weak pointer semantics. Possible?

Neither of those is possible.

The first one, having the lifetime of the *shared object* managed by some other object, violates the basic purpose of `shared_ptr` as a class. The point being that, so long as you have a `shared_ptr`, the thing it points to will *always exist*. Even with an intrusive pointer, you've violated the intrusive pointer contract if you get an intrusive pointer to it and later destroy it via other means.

The second one doesn't work, because weak pointer semantics are at their core based on the fact that the lifetime of the *control block* can exceed the lifetime of the object the control block manages. If both objects' lifetimes are managed by some containing object `Foo`, then when `Foo` is destroyed, both are destroyed. So the control block's lifetime ends before the weak pointers have all been destroyed.

So no, this doesn't work.

Now yes, there are ways to make such a weak pointer work, but those ways are... unpleasant. It requires having a linked list of all such weak pointer objects, and nulling them out when the control block is destroyed. But thread safety becomes either impossible (imagine copying such a weak pointer while the control block is being destroyed) or requires heavy-weight mutex locking for basic copy operations.

Overall, what you want is simply not what `std::shared_ptr` is for. What you're looking for is an intrusive pointer. And there's a reason why most intrusive pointer proposals don't have weak semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Aliasing constructor might help:

```
struct Bar {};
struct Foo
{
    std::shared_ptr<Bar> x;
    Bar y;
};

auto foo = std::make_shared<Foo>();
foo->x = std::make_shared<Bar>();
std::shared_ptr<Bar> py{foo, &foo.y}; // use control block of foo
```

Comment: But that means there are two `Bar` objects, and you've still heap-allocated the control block.